# Work word problems: How many additional workers needed with time contraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

So, I have apparently forgotten entirely how I used to approach such problems. A sample statement is as follows:

> 24 trained workers can complete a task in 16 days, whereas 32
>   untrained workers do the same task in 24 days. If 16 trained and 16
>   untrained workers do the work together for 12 days; how many more
>   trained workers are needed to complete the remaining work in 2 days?

Based on what I remember, I have:

Work done by trained person per day $ = \dfrac{1}{16 \cdot 24} $ and 
work done by untrained person per day $ = \dfrac{1}{24 \cdot 32} $. Since 16 each of them work together, they can complete the whole work in $ 16 $ days.

And this is where I get stuck. Now they have 4 days worth of work remaining. What should I do now?

Comment: I remember how to do these by considering them to be generalized distance/rate/time problems. See my [17 July 2006 alt.math.undergrad](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4924515) post for an example. This works for me because "$d = rt$" is not something I've ever forgotten, and even if I did, I can easily reproduce it by using that fact that "rate" is measured in units like "miles/hr" and "km/hr" (thus, rate = distance/time, so rate*distance = time).

Comment: "*thus, rate = distance/time, so rate$\cdot$distance = time*" Of course, this should be "thus, rate = distance/time, so rate$\cdot$time = distance"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$16$ trained workers working for 12 days do $16\cdot \frac 1{16\cdot24}\cdot 12 = 1/2$ of work.
$16$ untrained do $16\cdot\frac 1{24\cdot32}\cdot 12=1/4$ in the same time.
So the team does $3/4$ of work in $12$ days.

For the remaining $1/4$ to be completed in $2$ days you need additional $n$ untrained workes which satisfies:
'work done by 16 trained and (16+n) untrained in 2 days = 1/4'.